# Issue when slicing a pandas MultiIndex containing tuples

Tags: pandas, indexing, multi-index

I found a weird behaviour when slicing on multiindex where the index is a tuple

```
tmp=pd.Series(0,index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
   (('a',),),
   (('b',),),
   (('c','cc'),),
   (('d','dd'),),
                          ]))

print(tmp.reindex(tmp.index[1:]))
```

yields the following results

```
(b,)       0.0
(c, cc)    NaN
(d, dd)    NaN
```

Am I using the multiIndex incorrectly or is it a bug?
(pandas version='1.1.0')

Comment: Update your version of Pandas. Your code works well for me. It gives 0 for the last 2 rows (not NaN)

Comment: @Corralien what version are you using?

Comment: I use `Pandas==1.4.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well with a recent version of Pandas.

Output:

```
# pd.__version__: '1.4.1'
>>> tmp.reindex(tmp.index[1:])
(b,)       0
(c, cc)    0
(d, dd)    0
dtype: int64
```

Is it what you expect?

Comment: Yes, your output is my expection. It seems it affect pandas at least 1.1.0 to 1.1.5 - upgrading to 1.4.1 does solve the pb - thanks for the  pointing that out!